# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Missing required parameters for [Route: trainingcategories.update]

Tags: php, laravel, view, model, controller

Can seam to figure out what the problem is the model is not returning any data, I have check the  controller, view ,route and everything seem to be ok.

```
    public function edit(TrainingCategory $trainingCategory)
    {
        return view('admin.trainingcategories.edit')->with(['trainingcategory'=>$trainingCategory]);
    }
```

Here is my controller method, $trainingCategory does not return the required data from the database.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('is_admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@adminHome')->name('admin.home');
    Route::resource('positions', 'PositionsController');
    Route::resource('departments', 'DepartmentsController');
    Route::resource('trainings', 'TrainingsController');
    Route::resource('trainingcategories', 'TrainingCategoriesController');
    Route::get('/trainingcategories/{id}/{action}', 'TrainingCategoriesController@changestatus')->name('trainingcategories.status');
});
```

Here is my route file showing the code

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
<div class="app-main__inner">
    <div class="app-page-title">
        <div class="page-title-wrapper">
            <div class="page-title-heading">
                <div class="page-title-icon">
                    <i class="pe-7s-user icon-gradient bg-mean-fruit">
                    </i>
                </div>
                <div>Edit Training Category
                    <div class="page-title-subheading">Modify.
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="page-title-actions">

                <div class="d-inline-block dropdown">
                    <a href="{{ route('trainingcategories.create') }}" type="button"  class="btn-shadow  btn btn-info">

                        Create New Training Category
                        <span class="btn-icon-wrapper pr-2 opacity-7">

                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{ route('trainingcategories.index') }}" type="button"  class="btn-shadow  btn btn-primary">

                        List  Training Categories
                        <span class="btn-icon-wrapper pr-2 opacity-7">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-w-20"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
    </div>            
   <!--Data table section-->

   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">

        <nav class="" aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('admin.home') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('trainingcategories.index') }}">Training Category</a></li>
                <li class="active breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">Edit Training Category</li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
           <!--alerts-->
           @if(!empty($errors->all()) )

                          <div class="alert alert-danger fade show" role="alert">
                              @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                      <li>{{ $error }}</li>     
                              @endforeach
                          </div>
            @endif
            <!--end alerts--> 
        <div class="main-card mb-3 card">
        <div class="card-body"><h3 class="h4">Edit Training Category > <b>{{ $trainingcategory->name }}</b><br>
                <small class="muted">Modify</small></h3>
                <hr>
                <form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="POST" action="{{ route('trainingcategories.update',['trainingcategory'=>$trainingcategory->id]) }}">
                    @csrf
                    @method('PUT')
                        <div class="department-relative form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="">Name</label>
                                <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter training category" type="text" class="form-control" 
                                value="{{ old('name',$trainingcategory->name) }}" required>
                                <div class="valid-feedback">
                                    Looks good!
                                </div>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Please enter training category.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="department-relative form-group">
                            <label for="description" class="">Active<i class="muted"></i></label>
                            @include('includes._active_select')
                            </div>
                        <div class="department-relative form-group">
                            <label for="description" class="">Training Description<i class="muted">(Optional)</i></label>
                            <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control" required> {{ old('description',$trainingcategory->description) }} </textarea>
                            <div class="valid-feedback">
                                Looks good!
                            </div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Please enter training description.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="mt-1 btn btn-primary">update</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

        </div>
</div>
</div>
     <!-- form validation-->
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
'use strict';
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
// Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
// Loop over them and prevent submission
var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
}, false);
});
}, false);
})();
</script>
   <!--end data table section-->


</div>

@endsection
```

Here is my view

Comment: You haven't included the code where you're actually calling `route('trainingcategories.update')` - can you include that?

Comment: It  here in my view `<form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="POST" action="{{ route('trainingcategories.update',['trainingcategory'=>$trainingcategory->id]) }}">`

Comment: call php artisan route:list find the route trainingcategories.update and see what the route parameter you are missing is named, clearly something off with the naming. Im guessing it doesnt know how to go from plural to singular when you have not camel cased trainingcategories.

Comment: Just tested my comment and the naming seem to be fine, but still try to run php artisan route:list to see whats going on

Comment: I did  here is my route list snippet `  
  | PUT|PATCH | admin/trainingcategories/{trainingcategory}      | trainingcategories.update  | App\Http\Controllers\TrainingCategoriesController@update               | web,is_admin   `

Answer (score 2):

Guys I finally figured it out by changing the variable name trainingCategory to $trainingcategory (note the lowercase 'c', matching the resource route naming).So the resource return the data form the database.

Laravel automatically resolve type-hinted  models defined in routes or controller actions whose variable names match a route segment name.

Comment: You're right! 
I had the change method argument's name to Category instead of productCategory to have the same naming like route:list results in { }=> product/categories/{category}

Answer (score 0):

The error is related with [Route: trainingcategories.update]. 
When you did:

```
Route::resource('trainingcategories','TrainingCategoriesController');
```

You generate this route: trainingcategories.update that is waiting $trainingcategories param in your update method at TrainingCategoriesController.

like this:

```
public function update(TrainingCategory $trainingCategory)
```

so, you need to see update method. edit method isn't guilted.

Comment: I have not submitted the form yet

Answer (score 0):

You've shown that this is how you're generating the route:

```
route('trainingcategories.update',['trainingcategory'=>$trainingcategory->id])
```

You don't need to pass in the associative array, you can pass the model in.

```
route('trainingcategories.update', $trainingcategory)
```

Make sure that `$traningcategory` actually exists and that the ID property is not null. Laravel is complaining that it's not getting the required parameter.

Comment: The id is not null, but the model $trainingCategory returns null inside ` public function edit(TrainingCategory $trainingCategory)
    {
        return view('admin.trainingcategories.edit')->with(['trainingcategory'=>$trainingCategory]);
    }`

Comment: Here is my migration for the table `public function up()` $table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');  $table->text('description')->nullable(); $table->tinyinteger('active')->default('1'); $table->timestamps();`